# DataGridView Object Databinding Issue "Index -1 does not have a value"

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am using a set of DataGridViews (dgv) to display a class's members via properties.  I use the dgv so that the user can edit the value of the member right in the view (so I dont have to display a form or a textbox for editing that value).

The structure of the class I am displaying is as follows

```
 Class1 (Displayed in a list view)
     Collection Of class2 (Displayed in a dgv, we'll call it dgv1)
          Collection of class3 (Displayed in a dgv, we'll call it dgv2)
```

Class3 exists because a collection of strings does not show up as strings in a dgv. (The length is displayed in the dgv.

Class2 and Class3 have string properties that I want editable in the dgv, so they are the only values displayed in the dgv.

When I add a new instance of either class2 or class3 to their respective parent class, I rebind the dgv displaying the collection.

After adding the new instance of the class, it appears in the dgv, but if I go to select the value (by clicking on it in the dgv) I get an exception stating "Index -1 does not have a value"

The issue does not occur if I save the information edited into the form and then reopen the form.  The values that I could not previously edit are editable without issue.

Comment: What part of the code would be helpful to post?  There is a lot of code in this form.  Would you like to see the classes or form code?

Comment: How do you rebind the dgv after adding either class2 or class3 to their parents?

Comment: I rebind the controls by calling the method I originally called to bind them.

Comment: Did you ever find out what was causing this?

Comment: Never did :(  I left that job as well, so the question no longer applies

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I know this question is old but:

If you initially bind an ***empty*** collection that does not inform the DGV of changes (e.g. a Collection does not, but a BindingList does), the initial current row offset will be correctly set to -1, (Because it is empty.)

When you subsequently add objects to your data bound collection they will still ***display*** correctly on the grid, but the CurrencyManager will not be informed of any changes, and the current row offset will remain stubbornly at -1.

So, when you try to edit a row, the CurrencyManager thinks you are trying to edit a row at offset -1, and the exception is thrown.

To combat this, you need to rebind before interacting with a row, or initially bind a Collection etc when it contains one or more items.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my datasource from List(Of T) to List(Of T).ToArray()

Comment: Adding some explanations as to why this solves the problem would help immensely.

Answer (score 0):

I also know it's old, but I struggled with this, and the best solution I found is using BindList instead of a regular list.

Answer (score 0):

I just recently ran into a very similar issue of "Index -1" in a very simple application that was doing a "display only" of selectable data sets. It was completely my fault as I had used List which worked just fine until suddenly it didn't. Switching to BindingList resolved it.