# Windows form application exception

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

I get application exception

```
   at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.get_Current()
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.OnRowEnter(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnRowEnter(DataGridViewCell& dataGridViewCell, Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean canCreateNewRow, Boolean validationFailureOccurred)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.SetCurrentCellAddressCore(Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean setAnchorCellAddress, Boolean validateCurrentCell, Boolean throughMouseClick)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellMouseDown(HitTestInfo hti, Boolean isShiftDown, Boolean isControlDown)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellMouseDown(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseDown(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at MedForms.Program.Main() in F:\Projects\Vstu\MedForms\MedForms\Program.cs:line 18
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

each time when I try to click on DataGridView.

I get error message

> {"Index -1 does not have a value."}
>   (SystemIndexOutOfaRange exception).

on row

```
Application.Run(new MainForm());
```

and I am not able to debug it. Please help me find what can cause such problem and how I can to debug it?

Comment: What is the exception message?  Your biggest clue right now is the reference to `CurrencyManager`.  What is the grid doing with currency?  Specifically, is there anything wrong with the data in the row you're clicking on?

Comment: Along with David, what is the full stack trace?  This is missing the important information

Comment: It is full stack trace. There is nothing else... I can olly add that error message is {"Index -1 does not have a value."} (SystemIndexOutOfaRange exception). I added it to question.

Comment: My bet is on "IndexOutOfRangeException" because the CurrencyManager is reporting a current row position offset of -1.

Comment: I don't work with currency. DataGridView have only 5 columns: 1 Date, 2 text and 2 buttons.

Comment: @Anton: I do not mean currency meaning money. Data binding uses a CurrencyManager to keep track of the *current* row, etc.

Comment: In our case the problem was that one of our programmers disabled the events under some circumstances with: this.RaiseListChangedEvents = false;

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm guessing that you have bound a List that is initially empty, (or other sort of collection that does not generate list changed events) to your `DataGridView`, and then added items to this List.

The items you add will ***display*** correctly on your grid, but clicking on a row will cause this exception. This is because the underlying `CurrencyManager` will be reporting its current row position as an offset of -1. It will stay this way because the List does not report changes to the grid.

You should only bind your list to the grid if it has some items in it to begin with, or rebind when you add them.

See also my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435526/datagridview-object-databinding-issue-index-1-does-not-have-a-value/4485009#4485009) question, which is essentially the same problem.

Comment: Yes, I am binding list. I will try to check if list is empty before binding.

Comment: The problem could be solved if before binding data `List<of T>` to `DataGridView` need to convert `List<of T>`  to `DataTable` (by converting `List<of T>` to `DataTable`) and use it as `DataSource`. For me it’s better than converting to `BindingList (of T)`, because after databinding `DataGridView.DataSource =  BindingList (of T)` it shows 1 empty row in `DataGridView`, even `BindingList (of T)` is empty

Comment: While binding the list (Lets Assume DataLst) to the Data Source of the DataGridView, bind it with Grid.DataSource = DataLst.ToList();

Answer (score 1):

Following Andy's advice I substituted

```cs
private List<Employee> Employees { get; set; } = new List<Employee>();
_employeesGridView.DataSource = Employees;
```

with

```cs
private BindingList<Employee> Employees { get; set; } = new BindingList<Employee>();
_employeesGridView.DataSource = Employees;
```

and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of effort i have solved this issue. Bind your DataGridView When you have some data in the Data Source either it would be a list or DataTable.