# Index-1 does not have a value

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm getting the strangest error I am absolutely clueless about. I'll post a description along with some code here, and hopefully one of you guys can point me in the right direction.

My app (Winforms), allows a user to add items to a datagridview (bound to a list), and everytime an item is added, the list is serialized to a xml file. When the application is initially launched, the program checks for the xml file, and if found, adds the previously added items to the dgv.

Ive also added a DataGridViewButtonColumn to delete items from the dgv (list). Here is some of the code.

**Main class:**

```
 static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new formFoldingClient());
        }
```

**The form's constructor calls this method to initially set up the dgv**

```
private void InitialDataGridViewSetup()
        {
            dgvClients.DataSource = null;

            //adding delete button column
            DataGridViewButtonColumn btnDelete = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
            btnDelete.Name = "btnDelete";
            btnDelete.Text = "Delete";
            btnDelete.HeaderText = "Delete";
            btnDelete.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
            btnDelete.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.DarkBlue;
            btnDelete.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
            dgvClients.Columns.Add(btnDelete);

            RefreshDataGridView();
        }
```

Everytime an item is added or removed, the dgv is refreshed by calling this method:

```
 private void RefreshDataGridView()
            {
                dgvClients.DataSource = null;

                if (clientList.Count != 0)
                {
                    dgvClients.DataSource = clientList;
                    dgvClients.Show();
                    dgvClients.ClearSelection();


                }
            }

Method that gets triggered when Delete button on a row in the dgv is pressed, followed by the method the performs the delete

 private void dgvClients_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 0) //delete button has been clicked
            {
                DeleteClient(dgvClients.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex + 1].FormattedValue.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void DeleteClient(string clientToDelete)
        {
            dgvGrid.DataSource = null;
            int removeAt = new int();

            for (int i=0; i<clientList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (clientList[i]._ClientName == clientToDelete)
                {
                    removeAt = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            clientList.RemoveAt(removeAt);
            LogToFile("Removed client: " + clientToDelete);
            LogToBox("Removed client: " + clientToDelete);
            RefreshDataGridView();
            SaveConfigAsXml();
            LogToFile("Changes after deletion persisted to clients.xml.");

        }
```

I believe this is all the code that should be necesarry. If you need anymore, do let me know.

**Problem brief**
When the app first loads if it finds the xml and loads those items to the list, everything performs as expected. I can add more items, delete all items (one at a time) etc.

However, if I start without an initial xml, adding items is not a problem. But when I delete the last remaining item in the dgv, I get the following exception at the last line of `Main()`

```
Index out of range Exception: {"Index -1 does not have a value."}
```

**Stack Trace**

```
at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.get_Current()
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.OnRowEnter(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnRowEnter(DataGridViewCell& dataGridViewCell, Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean canCreateNewRow, Boolean validationFailureOccurred)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.SetCurrentCellAddressCore(Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean setAnchorCellAddress, Boolean validateCurrentCell, Boolean throughMouseClick)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellMouseDown(HitTestInfo hti, Boolean isShiftDown, Boolean isControlDown)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellMouseDown(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseDown(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at FoldingMonitorLocalClient.Program.Main() in C:\Users\xbonez\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\FoldingClient\FoldingClient\Program.cs:line 17
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

**More Info
So, I just realized that if I have n items in the dgv, deleting just the first item also causes the same exception. Deleting items 2 to n is no problem.**

**Code that reads xml and adds to list**

```
 private void ReadFromConfigFile()
        {
            LogToFile("Beginning to read from clients.xml.");

            XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Client>));

            try
            {
                List<Client> tempClientList = new List<Client>();
                using (Stream reader = new FileStream("clients.xml", FileMode.Open))
                {
                    tempClientList = ((List<Client>)deserializer.Deserialize(reader));
                }

                foreach (Client client in tempClientList)
                {
                    clientList.Add(client);
                }
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
            {
                //config file does not exist
                this.LogToBox("No saved settings found.");
                this.LogToFile("No existing clients.xml present.", ex);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogToBox("Unable to load saved settings. Please see log for more details.");
                LogToFile("Failed to read clients.xml.", ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                LogToFile("Finished reading clients.xml.");
            }
        }
```

**Code when add button is clicked**

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.tbxClientName.BackColor = Color.White;
            this.tbxLogLoc.BackColor = Color.White;

            bool exists = false;

            foreach (Client client in clientList)
            {
                if (client._ClientName == this.tbxClientName.Text)
                    exists = true;
            }

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbxClientName.Text))
            {
                this.tbxClientName.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                LogToBox("Enter Client Name");
                LogToFile("user attempted to add client without specifying client name.");
            }
            else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbxLogLoc.Text))
            {
                this.tbxLogLoc.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                LogToBox("Select WorkLog location.");
                LogToFile("User attempted to add client without specifying worklog location.");
            }
            else if (exists)
            {
                //client name entered by user already exists
                LogToBox("Client name " + this.tbxClientName.Text + " already exists. Enter another Client name.");
                LogToFile("Duplicate client name entered.");
                this.tbxClientName.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            }
            else
            {
                //everything is valid. Add new client to list
                clientList.Add(new Client(tbxClientName.Text, tbxLogLoc.Text));
                LogToBox("Added new client: " + tbxClientName.Text + ".");
                LogToFile("Added new client: " + tbxClientName.Text + ".");

                this.tbxClientName.Text = String.Empty;
                this.tbxLogLoc.Text = String.Empty;

                RefreshDataGridView();
                SaveConfigAsXml();
            }            
        }
```

Comment: Since, I do not encounter the error when items are read from the xml, but only when user manually adds items, I'm posting both the code fragments too

Comment: The good explanation i've found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494147/windows-form-application-exception

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This seems to be some kind of internal binding bug in .NET. 
I experienced exactly the same exception whenever using DataGridView bound to a List.
I really spent a lot of time trying to find a solution and I've finally managed to get rid of these exceptions today - by **adding ICurrencyManagerProvider interface to all my Lists**. 
This interface only has a "CurrencyManager" read-only property and a "GetRelatedCurrencyManager" method. 
I'm just returning Nothing in both of them and that's it, no more CurrencyManager "index -1 does not have a value" stuff.

> EDIT: OK, just found out the "proper way" is actually to use **BindingList(of T)** class instead of **List(of T)**

Comment: +1 BindingList is definitely the collection to use when binding data to the DataGridView

Comment: The problem could be solved if before binding data `List<of T>` to `DataGridView` need to convert `List<of T>`  to `DataTable` (by converting `List<of T>` to `DataTable`) and use it as `DataSource`. For me it’s better than converting to `BindingList (of T)`, because after databinding `DataGridView.DataSource =  BindingList (of T)` it shows 1 empty row in `DataGridView`, even `BindingList (of T)` is empty

Comment: +infinite for the `BindingList(of T)`

Comment: Using BindingList is the real solution

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

Modify the dgvClients_CellClick method to include more checks:

```
 if (e.ColumnIndex == 0) //delete button has been clicked
            {
                if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
                {
                    DataGridViewRow dataGridViewRow = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

                    if (dataGridViewRow.Cells.Count > 1)
                    {
                        DeleteClient(dataGridViewRow.Cells[e.ColumnIndex + 1].FormattedValue.ToString());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    LogToFile(e.RowIndex.ToString());
                }
            }
```

You could modify the check in `dgvClients_CellClick` to include `e.RowIndex > 0` which should prevent the exception. Other than that, to know the exact reason for the behavior we would have to look at the **add item** logic and may be also the clientList.

May be you have to set the selected row index after you add items manually.

Comment: I'll give your solution a shot and see if it wrks. If not, I'll post some more of the code. Thanks.

Comment: Tried That....same error. The add items logic is in the method RefreshDataGridView().

Comment: Are you sure the exception is thrown when you are deleting a last item? The stack trace says something else, it is like the exception is thrown when the form is loading or something?

Comment: I only get the exception when I delete the first item in the dgv when it has NOT loaded from the XML. The stack trace threw me off too, but the form loads perfectly, until I attempt to delete the first item.

Comment: the call to ClearSelection removes the selected row index, and hence calling the delete passes RowIndex = -1 to your cell Click handler.

Answer (score 2):

This Microsoft Winforms bug (crashing when clicking on DataGrid bound to a list) is still present when binding a list to a DataGrid in Visual Studio 16.7.7 running .NET 4.8.03752. Note that the code below ALSO produces the same bug, even when using a BindingList, if you specify a binding source:

```
var myProblems = new List<Problems>();
var bindingList = new BindingList<Problems>(myProblems);
var source = new BindingSource(bindingList, null);
myDataGrid.DataSource = source;
```

However, if we don't use a BindingSource and do it directly this way, then the bug does not occur:

```
var myProblems = new BindingList<Problems>();
myDataGrid.DataSource = myProblems;
```

Also note that if you are binding a List to a DataGrid, the Class members must be Properties (as in {get; set;} and not fields (as in int MyField;) because the DataGrid won't bind to Fields, even if declared public.