# C# DataGridView (IndexOutOfRangeException) (operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function)

Tags: c#, datagridview, indexoutofrangeexception

My initial code which cause the issue:

```cs
dataGridView1.DataSource = new BindingSource().DataSource = myDataSourceVar;
```

And it fixed by changing it to:

```cs
BindingSource myBindingSource = new BindingSource();
myBindingSource.DataSource = myDataSourceVar;
dataGridView1.DataSource = myBindingSource ;
```

Problems:
What is the differences between those two codes that cause the issue? as I only think that my initial code is the one line more clean code than the other one.

Error References:

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index -1 does not have a value.
   at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.OnRowEnter(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnRowEnter(DataGridViewCell& dataGridViewCell, Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean canCreateNewRow, Boolean validationFailureOccurred)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.SetCurrentCellAddressCore(Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean setAnchorCellAddress, Boolean validateCurrentCell, Boolean throughMouseClick)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellMouseDown(HitTestInfo hti, Boolean isShiftDown, Boolean isControlDown)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellMouseDown(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseDown(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index -1 does not have a value.
operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function.
```

Other References:

1. [Windows form application exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494147/windows-form-application-exception)
2. [DataGridView Object Databinding Issue "Index -1 does not have a value"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435526/datagridview-object-databinding-issue-index-1-does-not-have-a-value/4485009#4485009)

Comment: Try putting parentheses around `new BindingSource().DataSource = myDataSourceVar`, as in `(new BindingSource().DataSource = myDataSourceVar)`

Comment: In any case, your two code examples are *not identical.*  Your second code example contains an additional reference: `myBindingSource`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I had tried putting those parentheses, but in Visual Studio. those parentheses is blurred out as it may think that it is unnecessary.

Comment: Did it solve the problem anyway?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I solved my problem by rewriting those code as what I posted above. Adding those parentheses its not fixing it.